# django doesn't dump tables into database

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm having trouble trying to dump tables into a sqlite database. My settings.py is as follows:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'untitled4'
]
```

untitled4 is the automatic name PyCharm gave to my application which I'm using to test out the issue. This is my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()
```

But when I open the database, only a bunch of irrelevant info come up:

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZAVv.png)

Why is that and what am I doing wrong when I run `manage.py migrate`?

Comment: You need to make migrations first: `manage.py makemigrations`, then `manage.py migrate`.

Comment: This comes up so frequently -- not doing `makemigrations` -- it seems like it should be part of the error message.

Comment: @PeterRowell: this didn't solve my problem. Console just says "No changes detected" and defaults. It doesn't create migrations folder either.

Comment: You need to run `manage.py makemigrations untitled4` to create the initial migration if the folder doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `settings.py`correctly configured to use the SQL file you are looking at?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```